# INSERT INTO statement with parameters for tableName, columns and values?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql, parameter

Is it possible to have an SP that looks something like this:

```
DECLARE @tableName = null;
DECLARE @cols = null;
DECLARE @values = null;

INSERT INTO @tableName @cols @values;
```

The resultant query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO <table name> (<set of column names>) VALUES (<set of corresponding values>);
```

My use case is that I'm parsing Excel data into a database, i.e. a single workbook of 'type X' equates to a single row in this database. These workbooks are filled in from a template, so the data format is pretty constant. To parse the data I create a sheet in the workbook called '*DATA*' or something, that looks like this:

```
tableName | attributeName | attributeValue | .. plus some config stuff
People    | Firstname     | Johnny         | etc
People    | Lastname      | Heinz          | etc
People    | Firstname     | Sam            | etc
People    | Lastname      | Smith          | etc
```

This would equate to two rows in the `People` table of the database (multiple rows are recognized by repeating `attributeNames` for a specific table).

The reasons this needs to be dynamic SQL is:

1. I'd like this to be applicable to any table in the database
2. I won't know how many cols a particular table has before parsing

Comment: as far as you must build your insert query, add DECLARE sentences there

Comment: So the `@tableName , @cols, @values` are the parameter for the SPs?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.... @McNets

Comment: @Arulkumar. Yes.

Comment: In my opinion this job requires a dynamic query.

Comment: At the moment I'm building up a string and passing that as a param to sp_executeSQL. Is there a better, more secure way?

Comment: Building up a string where? And are you really building up a string of parameter *values*? What if there are ints, dates, binary, etc.? Why are the column names dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't parameterize table names or column names - you'll have to use dynamic SQL.
2. You should also be passing the table's *schema*.
3. You should be validating table names and column names. Table names are easy to check, but for column names we'll use this function:

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ParseColumnList
   (
     @List NVARCHAR(MAX)
   )
   RETURNS TABLE
   AS
     RETURN   
     (
       SELECT i, 
         c = LTRIM(CONVERT(SYSNAME, SUBSTRING(@List, i, 
             CHARINDEX(',', @List + ',', i) - i)))
       FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) 
             FROM sys.all_columns) AS n(i)
       WHERE i <= LEN(@List) AND SUBSTRING(',' + @List, i, 1) = ','
     );
   ```
4. You should be using strongly-typed parameters for parameter values, to protect yourself from SQL injection vulnerabilities. Understanding where these parameter values come from will help to further refine this solution, but for now you'll just have to blindly append your values list and hope for the best:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.DealersChoice
     @TableSchema   sysname,
     @TableName     sysname,
     @ColumnList    nvarchar(max),
     @ParamValues   nvarchar(max)
   AS
   BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     IF NOT EXISTS ( -- make sure table exists:
       SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables AS t
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
         ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
         WHERE t.name = QUOTENAME(@TableName)
         AND s.name = QUOTENAME(@TableSchema)
     )
     BEGIN -- raise an appropriate error here
       RETURN;
     END

     IF EXISTS ( -- make sure columns exist:
       SELECT 1 FROM dbo.ParseColumnList(@ColumnList) AS f
         LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON f.c = c.name
         WHERE c.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(@TableSchema)
           + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName))
       WHERE c.name IS NULL
     )
     BEGIN -- raise appropriate error
       RETURN;
     END

     DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'INSERT '
       + QUOTENAME(@TableSchema) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
       + N' (' + @ColumnList + N') VALUES(' + @ParamValues + N');';

     EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
   END
   ```

I am not sure how you are building the `@ParamValues` parameter but if you have string delimiters embedded in it (like `5, 'foo', '20160206'`), you'll need to double those up *somewhere* so that it becomes `5, ''foo'', ''20160206''` - this becomes a challenge when you have strings like `O'Brien` - one of just many reasons why you should be using proper parameters instead of concatenating one big string with all your values.

See the following:

- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer - that is very helpful. I was considering doing basic checks within the C# code during data parsing for any obvious form of SQL injection. But I see validation will be more reliable in the database. I've added a use-case for this to my question.

Comment: I've seen that the table I'm attempting to INSERT into does typecasting, i.e. a value of '0.02' will successfully insert to a column of type `decimal(7,4)`. My strings will almost certainly have commas and apostrophe's that shouldn't be seen as delimiters.

Comment: Note: for the name `O'Bryan` to parse correctly, it would have to go in as `'O''Bryan'`; at that point, doubling all the apostrophes would have the desired affect.