# Are there any pitfalls to be aware of when using dynamic type-coercion in SQL Server?

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, type-conversion, table-valued-parameters

I want to insert into a database with a query that looks something like the following:

```
INSERT INTO <table name> (<set of column names>) VALUES (<set of corresponding values>);
```

As I mentioned on a previous answer **[here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/sql-server-insert-into-statement-with-parameters-for-tablename-columns-and-val)**. The answer to that question was to create a string of values and then treat that string as a comma separated list. Just before I implement that, I want to know if building up a TVP is a viable solution. ***Two questions:***

**QUESTION 1: What to watch out for WRT type-coercion?**

The TVP will have a schema of:

```
| colName (nvarchar) | value (nvarchar |
```

And the values will be of type text, bool, int, decimal, date, etc. Is there anything I have to watch out for when converting types to nvarchar?

I will then by dynamically building up a sql query from the values in the TVP. Are there any potential problems with type coercion from nvarchar to any other SQL Server type?

**QUESTION 2: Is this a good idea?**

The answer to my previous question (as linked to above) suggests using NVARCHAR strings as a list of cols and vals. Between these two approaches, which would be considered preferable?

Comment: Actually, if you read the whole answer, you'll see I only showed you how to string all your values together because of the stated limitations in your question that prevented the better/safer things I suggested. For example, you said you didn't even know how many columns there are, so how could you possibly know their names, types, or precision? How could you make appropriate TVPs in advance?

Comment: Ah. I was assuming I could cast anything as varchar and that sql server will be fine with that. Will that not work?

Comment: In this case I'm going to loop through a list of colnames (that will correspond to a list of value), and insert a row of (col, val) for each col. Then in TSQL I'm going to iterate through the TVP and build up a dynamic SQL query

Comment: Well, casting nvarchar to varchar will lose data, if you have Unicode strings. And blindly converting certain dates and numerics to string will possibly break things, and can depend on where you change it to a string.

Comment: Your source data will be critical. If, for example, dates aren't being entered into spreadsheets in a consistent way, then it may be impossible to correctly translate those dates back into the same dates they started as. Normally, in Excel, you can control this by imposing a date format on a column. In your case, that's not a workable solution, especially if you have numbers and dates in the same column.

Comment: I'm scraping from an intermediate excel sheet where I have imposed date formats

Comment: Would it be possible to include a column in the spreadsheet that would specify type? If so, you might be able to format the data in Excel in advance.  Note: if nothing else, use nvarchar strings (`N'foo'`) instead of varchar strings (`'foo'`).

Comment: It would be, though I'n hoping i can take a javascriptesque approach to this... it seems to be working at the moment. Good entry into the world of TVPs and dynamic SQL!